# How to un-simplify a general term

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a general term of $\frac{3n-1}{5n+7}$ and I want to find out which term $\frac{7}{12}$ is. I have a number in mind that I got from just trial and error but how would I apply a formula to find this. I am treating it as an arithmetic sequence with a common difference of 3 on top and 5 on bottom. I then apply the nth term formula but can't seem to arrive at the right conclusion.

Comment: Are you asking what value of $n$ makes $\frac{3n-1}{5n+7} = \frac{7}{12}$? If so, this is an equation in the single variable $n$ that you can solve.

Comment: Well yes, I need to find which term it is so yes, if I can find n then n+1 would be the term. The problem is, it's obviously a simplified fraction so how do I work out what it's simplified from?

Comment: $$
\frac{{3n - 1}}{{5n + 7}} = \frac{7}{{12}} \Leftrightarrow 12(3n - 1) = 7(5n + 7) \Leftrightarrow 36n - 12 = 35n + 49
$$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

You can't treat $\frac{3n - 1}{5n + 7}$ as an arithmetic progression. For reference, let $a_{i} = \frac{3i - 1}{5i + 7}$. Then,

\begin{align*}
    a_{n} - a_{n - 1} &= \frac{3n - 1}{5n + 7} - \frac{3(n - 1) - 1}{5(n - 1) + 7} \\
    a_{n} - a_{n - 1} &= \frac{3n - 1}{5n + 7} - \frac{3n - 3 - 1}{5n - 5 + 7} \\
    a_{n} - a_{n - 1} &= \frac{3n - 1}{5n + 7} - \frac{3n - 4}{5n + 2} \\
    a_{n} - a_{n - 1} &= \frac{26}{25n^{2} + 45n + 14}
\end{align*}

As you can see, the difference of consecutive terms is not constant.

---

However, if you are solving for $n$  where $\frac{3n - 1}{5n + 7} = \frac{7}{12}$, just proceed with rules of rational equations.

Comment: It's definitely a sequence and I can see patterns so am trying to work out how to use what I'm seeing to find out which term $\frac{7}{12}$ is. The way I see it as I start with n=1 and progress the numerator increases by 3 and the denominator increase by 5. I know the when I reach 61 I end up with $\frac{182}{312}$ which simplifies to $\frac{7}{12}$. I just can't seem to see what formula is getting me there.

Comment: @toby843 Did you read my comment below your question? It is a simple elementary school maths problem.

Comment: @Gary Hi, yes I saw your comment. I'm sorry, it's been 25 years since I was in elementary school and I can't really see what you're getting at. I'm trying to understand it in terms of sequences but it seems there's an easier way?

Comment: @toby843 It is $\frac{3n - 1}{5n + 7}$ that gets you there. But, I really don't get your usage of 'term'. If you are referring to something like $n$th term, then as you said, it is $n = 61$ that yields $\frac{7}{12}$, which means that $\frac{7}{12}$ is the $61$st term.

Comment: @toby843 Do you know that $$
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \Leftrightarrow ad = bc?
$$

Comment: @Gary Yes, and I can see that's what you were implying in your first comment. I'm not sure I get where it's going?

Comment: @soupless Hi, yes mate, it like an nth term question. I know that $\frac{7}{12}$ is the 61st term but I can't see how to get to that conclusion from the info in the original post.

Comment: @toby843 Do you know how to solve $36n - 12 = 35n + 49$ for $n$?

Comment: @toby843 Please refer to Gary's comment. Also, Gary, you might want to considering making your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Gary Amazing. I just worked that through and there it is. Lesson learned most definitely. Thank you both.

Comment: @soupless, as above. Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: I was definitely over thinking it. Trying to use nth term formulas etc and it was basic fractions. Thanks for the pointer!